# Spring Batch configuration Formatter Conversion change

Tags: printf, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin, spring-batch-job-monitoring, spring-batch-excel

I have an Item Writer as below:

```
<beans:property name="lineAggregator">
  <beans:bean class="org.spring...FormatterLineAggregator">
    <beans:property name="fieldExtractor">
        <beans:bean class="org.springframework..BeanWrapperFieldExtractor">
             <beans:property name="names" value="column1" /> 
            </beans:bean>
            </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="format" value="%05d" /> 
    </beans:bean>
```

when I tired with format value ="%05d" I getting my expected value as 00012. but when I tried by changing formatter value with value ="%05s" 
I am getting getting whitespaces like this  "     12" which need to be replaced with zero.

suppose if I have value as AI2 means then my formatted value has to be 000AI2. That's y I am trying to change conversion from d to s.

How to do that :?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**%d** is used to format numbers **only**. Usually in fixed lenght file we pad string data with spaces and numbers with "0".

If you have no choise and the data you want to pad with "0" is a String, maybe you can do the conversion logic in the processor of your step ?